# How to calculate the variation of curvature along the horizontal axis

Tags: plotting, data, scripting

I have a data set with $(x,y)$ coordinates. I do the following to import the data

```
data = Import[
   "plot.txt", "Table"];
x = data[[All, 2]]-250;
y = data[[All, 1]];
Newdata = Transpose[{x, y}];
p2 = ListPlot[Newdata, PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {34, 36}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]
```

And I obtain the following plot [image]

Edit: This is my attempt

```
intp = Interpolation[Transpose[{x, y}]];
d1[t_] := D[{s, intp[s]}, s] /. s -> t;
d2[t_] := D[{s, intp[s]}, {s, 2}] /. s -> t;
k[t_] := Det[{d1[t], d2[t]}]/Norm[d1[t]]^3;
(*find the min and max curvature so we can scale the colours*)

maxk = First[NMaximize[{k[t], 0 < t < Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, t]];
mink = First[NMinimize[{k[t], 0 < t < Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, t]];
Plot[intp[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{t}, Hue[Rescale[k[t], {mink, maxk}]]]]
```

I get the following error

```
Interpolation:The point 14 in dimension 1 is duplicated.
```

[image]

Now, I would like to know why I get such an error while calculating the variation of the mean curvature along the $x$-axis. Can anyone suggest how to approach that?

Comment: There are many ways to describe curvature. Which one do you want?

Comment: Wouldn't you first need to have a model of the function underlying your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Table[{x, Tanh[6 x] Exp[-x/2]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];
intp = Interpolation[data];

d1[t_] := D[{s, intp[s]}, s] /. s -> t;
d2[t_] := D[{s, intp[s]}, {s, 2}] /. s -> t;
k[t_] := Det[{d1[t], d2[t]}]/Norm[d1[t]]^3

(* find the min and max curvature so we can scale the colours *)
maxk = First[NMaximize[{k[t], 0 < t < Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, t]];
mink = First[NMinimize[{k[t], 0 < t < Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, t]];
Plot[intp[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{t}, Hue[Rescale[k[t], {mink, maxk}]]]]
```

[image: plot with curvature]

There's also a much simpler way to get curvature using `ArcCurvature`:

```
k[t_] := ArcCurvature[intp[s], s] /. s -> t
maxk = First[NMaximize[{k[t], 0 < t < Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, t]];
mink = First[NMinimize[{k[t], 0 < t < Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, t]];
Plot[intp[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{t}, Hue[Rescale[k[t], {mink, maxk}]]]]
```

Comment: as     In order to import the data ..I do  ArcCurvature[x, y] /. y -> t ?

Comment: No, you need to interpolate the data first. In your case: `intp = Interpolate[Transpose[{x, y}]]` or just replace `data` at the top of my code with `Transpose[{x, y}]`

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: No. I get an error The value function is not number from both the approaches.

Comment: @newstudent please add an update to your question with what you tried. It might help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: @newstudent Try changing `intp = Interpolation[Transpose[{x, y}]]` to `intp = Interpolation[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Transpose[{x, y}],First]]` - that should get rid of duplicate points

Comment: thanks. It does work. But is it possible to plot $\kappa$ vs $x$ plot ?As of now I have range for a dummy variable

Comment: Yes of course, just `Plot[k[t],{t,0,1}]` extending the limits `{t,0,1}` if necessary.